# Why can't I convert my UIImage to NSData?

Tags: swift, uiimage, type-conversion, nsdata

I have a UIImage, and I am trying to convert it into NSData in Swift 2 like this:

```
var cardImage = UIImage(named: "card")
let cardData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cardImage) as NSData?
```

However, `cardData` always returns nil and the error,

> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value."

Also, when I print out cardImage it gives, `<UIImage: 0x124eca4f0>, {0, 0}.`

Why is `cardData` nil? I don't understand what's wrong with the code. Please help!

Comment: That code does not compile. Please post your *real* code.

Comment: var cardImage = UIImage(named: "card") returns optional. You can try logging the output in console. Most probably it would be nil.

Answer (score -1):

Unwrap the optional image before converting it to Data:-

```
let cardImage = UIImage(named: "card")
let cardData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cardImage!) as? NSData
```

Comment: That gives me an error that says, "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'UIImage'."